Django loads static files from a whole diff project
I have two folders, each one containing a Django project, each project has a templates folder and a static folder, for the sake of simplicity lets just call them project A and B, the static folder has a sub folder called CSS for both of them now in project A i use
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = \[
BASE_DIR / "static",
\]


and i easily load my static files in my html no issue now in project B i write the same thing but instead of loading static files from B/static/css it loads them from A/static/css which is so weird and i've no clue how to fix it, why is this happening ?
So far I haven't tried anything specific as I expected the BASE_DIR to handle the project path effectively, I have been reading the docs, to no avail, and the only thing I can think of is moving the project folder, but why do I have to do that? Surely there is a better way so I can keep my folder organized

Press ctrl+f on the browser. Because your urls are same, the browser is using cached files.

Sadly Ctrl + f didn't do anything, however it seems browser is to blame since using a different browser fixed the issue which mean BASE_DIR does in fact works as intended, so thanks

Press ctrl+f5 on the browser. That was a mistake.

This( ctrl+f5 ) loads static files forcing a hard refresh. https://fabricdigital.co.nz/blog/how-to-hard-refresh-your-browser-and-clear-cache

Press ctrl + f5 on the browser. This ctrl + f5 forces a hard refresh clearing all browser caches.
See how to hard refresh your browser and clear cache.
